# Change global of state enum to int value in a function

Tags: c++, enums, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

It's been several months since I have a compilation error on when I want to change the value of an enumeration declared at the beginning of the program (global), in a function that replaces it with an integer.

Before I did not have this problem, but having switched my code from a mini arduino card, to ESP8266 the problem appeared .. It do not have the same compiler ??

The error below is still blocking and prevents me from advancing on my project .. I can not find the solution:

`ERROR : request for member 'state' in 'CYCLE_ARROSAGE', which is of non-class type '<anonymous enum>'`

Here is a simplified example of the problem:

```
enum {
    S, // SECURITE
    N, // NUIT
    J1_1, J1_2, J1_3,  // Luminosité 1
    J2_1, J2_2, J2_3,  // Luminosité 2
    J3_1, J3_2, J3_3, // Luminosité 3
} CYCLE_ARROSAGE; // SECURITE

void setup () {
    CYCLE_ARROSAGE = N; // OK
}

void loop () {
    CheckChangementCycleArrosage(J2_2);
}


void CheckChangementCycleArrosage(int NouveauCycle ){

     if(CYCLE_ARROSAGE != NouveauCycle){

          Serial.print("CYCLE CHECKE : ");
          Serial.println(NouveauCycle); // -> 6

          Serial.print("CYCLE CHECKE CAST: ");
          Serial.println(String(NouveauCycle)); // -> 6

          Serial.print("CYCLE ARROSAGE: ");
          Serial.println(CYCLE_ARROSAGE); // -> 1

          CYCLE_ARROSAGE = NouveauCycle; // -> ERROR
    }
}
```

What could be the solution? I do not understand..

Comment: To be honest, if you're using your enum like that, there's no real benefit of an enum over (e.g.) an int.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert int implicitly to anonymous enum. 
Possible solution is to use static cast from int to, but you should declare yout enum as not anonymous.

```
enum EnumName {S, // SECURITE
N, // NUIT
J1_1, J1_2, J1_3,  // Luminosité 1
J2_1, J2_2, J2_3,  // Luminosité 2
J3_1, J3_2, J3_3, // Luminosité 3
} CYCLE_ARROSAGE; // SECURITE

...

CYCLE_ARROSAGE = static_cast< EnumName >( NouveauCycle );
```

Answer (score 1):

Gover is correct, though there is a [nasty] solution which keeps the anonymous enum:

```
CYCLE_ARROSAGE = static_cast<decltype(CYCLE_ARROSAGE)>(NouveauCycle);
```

This [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e323e892f13fd166) because `CYCLE_ARROSAGE` still has a *type*.

It just doesn't have a type with a name that you can, er, type.

Of course, you could now give it one:

```
using MyEnumType = decltype(CYCLE_ARROSAGE);
CYCLE_ARROSAGE = static_cast<MyEnumType>(NouveauCycle);
```

[This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/212340f12afad3f9) is about as close to reflection in C++ as you'll get.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about such kind of solution.